# Displaying domain name or URL that is long or contains many words

Tags: website-design, legibility, readability, urls

**2 related problems:**

I have a domain name that is quite long. e.g. **www.expertscientificanalysis.com** I have another domain that is not neccesarily long but made up of many words. e.g. **www.iamagreatguyfact.com** I'm stuck with them. The problem is to someone who isnt familiar with these names, they may find it difficult to read i.e. where does one word start and another end.

**Aim:**

How do I best display these domain names when advertising the url's in order to increase legibility? For example when writing them in an email or displaying them on a graphic.

**Possible ideas:**

Do I use uppercase letters? e.g.  **www.ExpertScientificAnalysis.com** or **www.IAmAGreatGuyFact.com**

Do I increase spacing slightly between the words to differentiate them?

What are the pro's/con's to these ideas? Also, are there better ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using uppercase characters in domain names is fine because they are not case-sensitive. Servers may be case-sensitive, so you should make sure that long URLs do in fact work whatever case is used.

When typesetting long URLs, you can also make use of different styles. This works better with some font families than others.

www.**expert***scientific***analysis**.com

Answer (score 1):

If by "display" you mean "show on a web page" (as opposed to "format in the address bar of a browser") then you have many **Typographic** options.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkLcKa.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Color, Kerning, and other design factors can all make the win.  You may even be able to use them to turn around an otherwise silly name by giving it humor and character

Comment: do you think that using uppercase letters inside a URL looks amateurish?

Comment: @DaveHaigh personally I do not, but every skill-level of internet user I've asked about this says that they think it looks like anything from 'odd' to 'lame'.  This opinion only seems to apply to browser-address-basr URLs, and print URLs that lack great typographic style (e.g. professional design work)

Answer (score 0):

Think not only of memorability but searchability and easy access. Some ideas are:

- Uppercase letters are good, as they bring readability and sense to long URLs
- Provide QR codes and short URLs for mobile and Twitter services
- Work with SEO to allow people to find you with search engines using shaped keywords and #tags
- Promote slightly different keywords to forgive users' memory distortions (great guy, best guy etc.)
- Use social network to promote. Your Facebook page could be a bridge to your site
- Don't use spacing as it could be perceived as spaces

Comment: do you think that using uppercase letters inside a URL looks amateurish?

Comment: Absolutely no. But it is subjective. Readability is objective index and could be measured. Uppercase letters increase readability. Finally, do you want they could read your name?